# How to bind xsd to Java classes with element documentation?

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have some XML schema that i want to bind to Java classes with xjc. In my xsd I have some fragments like:

```
<xs:element name="author" type="author">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      The author of a book.
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

but those documentation is lost in java bindings.
How can I get the "The author of a book." fragment from java code?